# How to add a toggle button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a button in Google Map which is suppose to set the Drawing Manager to NULL when clicked

```
$("#pauseedit").on("click",function(){
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null); 
});
```

and it is working fine but I would like to make it toggle like

```
$("#pauseedit").on("click",toggle(){
 drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null); ,
 drawingManager.setDrawingMode(Polygon);

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember if you can access `drawingManager.drawingMode` value. If you do, you can by testing it with an if:

```
$( "#pauseedit" ).on( "click", function () {
    if ( drawingManager.drawingMode === null ){
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode( Polygon );
    }else{
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode( null );
    }
} );
```

If you can't, you could use a class on your `#pauseedit` to control that:

```
$( "#pauseedit" ).on( "click", function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('drawingModePolygon') ){
        //if has the class, it is on edit mode, turn it off
        $(this).addClass('drawingModeNull').removeClass('drawingModePolygon');
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode( null );
    }else{
        //otherwise add the class and change the drawing
        $(this).addClass('drawingModePolygon').removeClass('drawingModeNull');
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode( Polygon );
    }
} );
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawing#drawingmanager_options